# Flutter, can TextOverflow.ellipsis ignore final blank space before adding ellipses?

Tags: flutter

I'm using TextOverflow.ellipsis and have the following issue:

```
Text(
    'This is an example of a string that needs an ellipses',
    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
  )
```

Obviously it depends on the size of the Text widget and the font, etc, but when given the correct parameters the result will look like:

```
'This is an example of a string ...'
```

where I want it to look like this, ignoring the final blank space:

```
'This is an example of a string...'
```

Would appreciate any ideas how this might be achieved.

Answer (score -1):

By using `inputText.trim()`, you ensure that any leading or trailing whitespace is removed from the string before it is displayed in the Text widget with `TextOverflow.ellipsis`. This will result in the desired output where the ellipsis follows the last non-whitespace character without any extra spaces.

```
String inputText = 'This is an example of a string that needs an ellipses';

inputText = inputText.trim(); // Remove leading and trailing whitespace

Text(
  inputText,
  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
)
```

Comment: No, the ellipsis is being put into a random position within the String, not at the end of the line... please study my example properly.